# Verificar se tem mais de um caractere em uma String

Tags: java, string

Como eu posso verificar quantos "@" tem em uma String?

exemplo:

> "@Teste @Teste"

tem 2 `@`, como eu posso fazer essa verificação em java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Utilizando java 8:

```
String testString =  "@Teste @Teste@ a@A";
long a = testString.chars().filter(ch -> ch =='@').count();
System.out.println(a);
```

Resultado:

> 4

Veja funcionando: https://ideone.com/bbaLdF

[**Nesta resposta do SOEn**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35242882/5524514) tem várias outras formas de se fazer isso.

Answer (score 6):

Existem muitas formas de fazer isso:

Usando [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

```
String text = "@Teste @Teste";
int apache = StringUtils.countMatches(text, "@");
System.out.println("apache = " + apache);
```

Usando [Replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)):

```
int replace = text.length() - text.replace("@", "").length();
System.out.println("replace = " + replace);
```

Usando [ReplaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))(caso 1):

```
int replaceAll = text.replaceAll("[^@]", "").length();
System.out.println("replaceAll (caso 1) = " + replaceAll);
```

Usando [ReplaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))(caso 2):

```
int replaceAllCase2 = text.length() - text.replaceAll("\\@", "").length();
System.out.println("replaceAll (caso 2) = " + replaceAllCase2);
```

Usando [Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
int split = text.split("\\@",-1).length-1;
System.out.println("split = " + split);
```

Dentre outras, [veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35242882/5524514).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o método `countMatches`, da classe `StringUtils` do pacote `org.apache.commons.lang3`:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("@Teste @Teste", "@");
```